# Merge multiple XML in multiple subfolders with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am quite new to PowerShell. Currently, I'm struggling with the following setup.
There are several XML files contained in this folder structure:

```
Root
|_2020-XX-XX
   |_file1.xml
   |_file2.xml
|_2020-yy-yy
    |_file1.xml
    |_file2.xml
```

Now, I want to create a script that merges parts of each folder's xml files into one.

The result should look something like this:

```
|_2020-XX-XX
   |_file1.xml
   |_file2.xml
   |_newfile2020XXXX.xml
|_2020-yy-yy
    |_file1.xml
    |_file2.xml
    |_newfile2020YYYY.xml
```

So far, my script looks like this:

```
$date=Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
#Get the date for naming the output-file

$xmlFilePath = Get-ChildItem "\\Server\Rootfolder" -Recurse -Force | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
#Get and sort the xml-Files by date

$finalXml = "<root>"

foreach ($file in $_.xmlFilePath) {
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content $file
    $finalXml += $xml.root.InnerXml
}
$finalXml += "</root>"
#XML Object closer

([xml]$finalXml).Save("$pwd\newfile$date.xml")
```

While the debugger does not produce any error, the created file is

- neither saved in the correct directory ("$pwd" does not seem to be the correct variable)
- empty except for the `<root></root>` nodes.

I can't quite figure out what to do, to troubleshoot this and would be grateful for any advice on this.

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: `$_.xmlFilePath` -> `$xmlFilePath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to create one "merged" file per folder. That means you need two loops - one for the folders, and one for the files per folder.

```
$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"

Get-ChildItem "\\Server\Rootfolder" -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $folder = $_.FullName
    Write-Host "Processing $folder..."

    $allData = [xml]"<root></root>"

    Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "*.xml" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -like "newfile*") { return }
        Write-Host " -" $_.name

        $xml = New-Object xml
        $xml.Load($_.FullName)

        $imported = $allData.ImportNode($xml.DocumentElement, $true)
        $allData.DocumentElement.AppendChild($imported) | Out-Null
    }

    $finalPath = Join-Path $folder "newfile_$date.xml"
    $allData.Save($finalPath)
}
```

Apart from that, don't process XML as if it were plain text. Use `XmlDocument.Load()` and `XmlDocument.Save()` for reading and writing, and use `XmlDocument.ImportNode()` to transfer content from one document to another.

These two lines are synonymous for creating an `XmlDocument` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8)):

```
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
```

Doing so guarantees that input files are interpreted correctly for their file encoding (`[xml]$xml = Get-Content ...` does not guarantee that) and that generated output is proper XML as well (concatenating some strings and writing the result to file does not guarantee that).

It's also a good idea to exclude "merged" files (`if ($_.Name -like "newfile*") { return }`), so you don't end up adding them to each other recursively.

Comment: @nudZ Good to hear! :) (Don't forget to tick off the answer as accepted when it solves your issue.)

Comment: Alright. Just another thing: If I want to select a specific node-range to copy, i.e. the third one until the 5th one, how would I do that?

Comment: And additionally, how do I get the <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>  declaration?

Comment: @nudZ Second question first: The `<?xml version='1.0'?>` should be written to the file by the `.Save()` method. UTF-8 is the default encoding in XML, so when `encoding='utf-8'` is not explicitly declared, it is assumed, there is no reason spend more time here. (As a hint for further research, explicitly specifying an encoding can be done by setting up an `XmlWriter`.)

Comment: As for the first question: You can use `$xml.SelectNodes("/an/xpath/expression")` to select the node range you want, and then write a `foreach` loop to import and append them one by one.

Comment: @nudZ Oh, and as I just noticed, you can also force the XML declaration and output encoding by writing it into the initial string when creating the container document: `$allData = [xml]"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><root></root>"`. So using an `XmlWriter` for this is more trouble than it's worth in this case.

Comment: Okay, just another question. So I've altered the code:
        `$xml = New-Object xml
        $xml.Load($_.FullName)
        #Nutzung des .NET XML-Moduls zur Verarbeitung
        $xmlNode =   $xml.SelectNodes("/parentnode/")
        $xmlPath =   $xml.SelectNodes("/parent-node/nodes-to-be-copied-from-this-point-on/*")
        $imported = $allData.ImportNode($xml.$xmlPath, $true)
        $allData.$xmlNode.InsertAfter($imported, $allData.$xmlNode) | Out-Null`  unfortunately, the SelectNodes just returns a NULL .. Is it because of the 
hyphens?

Comment: @nudZ I wrote: *"and then write a `foreach` loop to import and append them one by one"*. You cannot import multiple nodes in a single step.

Comment: ...also your `.InsertAfter()` line does not make a lot of sense to me. What was wrong with `$allData.DocumentElement.AppendChild()`?

Comment: _also your .InsertAfter() line does not make a lot of sense to me. What was wrong with $allData.DocumentElement.AppendChild()?_ Well the thing is: I dont want insert the cut content of the other files right after the second Childnode. I thought I have to use InsertAfter() for that.. concerning the foreach: I don't know how to use it tbh. This is my first time using PowerShell in the first place...